# Formal proof that a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ is $O(x^n)$ and $\Omega(x^n)$

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, solution-verification, alternative-proof

What we aim to prove is that if we have a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$, then $f(x) = O(x^n)$, which is equivalent to

$$\exists k>0\;\exists x_{0}\;\forall x>x_{0}\;|f(x)|\leq k x^n$$

We know that

$$|f(x)| = |\sum _{i=0} ^{n}{a_i x^i}| \leq \sum _{i=0} ^{n}{|a_i| |x^i|}$$

by the triangle inequality (I'm not sure if it holds for $n$ variables).

Now notice that if $x > 1$ the following always holds
$$\forall a, b \in \mathbb{N} \; a \geq b \Rightarrow x^a \geq |x^b|$$

Therefore we know that for $x>1$

$$|f(x)| \leq \sum _{i=0} ^{n}{|a_i| |x^i|} \leq x^n \sum _{i=0} ^{n}{|a_i| }$$

And so if we set $k = \sum _{i=0} ^{n}{|a_i|}$ and $x_0=1$ the theorem is proved.

I'm not sure if this line of reasoning is correct, mostly because of the triangle inequality. Also, this seems rather complicated. Is there a more elegant proof of this fact?

Edit: Also, I'm not really sure how to prove this for $\Omega(x^n)$ and therefore also for $\Theta(x^n)$ since I cannot use the triangle inequality like in the proof for $O(n)$

Comment: The triangle inequality is fine. It is correct and personally I don't think that this is complicated, it is rather simple, so hurray, you got your proof!

Comment: Your generalisation of the triangle inequality is correct (why not try to prove it?). Proofs of estimates like this are rarely elegant, so don't be ashamed of what you've done.

Comment: I just started wondering how I would prove that for $\Theta(x^n)$, since I cannot use the triangle inequality.

Comment: That's another question. See if you can solve it for yourself. What you need to prove is that $\Omega(f) = \Omega(x^n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach (and how I like to think of it). Note that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x^n=a_n\neq 0$ and hence $\lim_{x\to\infty} |f(x)/x^n|=|a_n|.$ Now choose $\epsilon=|a_n|$, then there exists an $x_0$ such that for all $x>x_0$, we have $|f(x)/x^n|\in (|a_n|-\epsilon, |a_n|+\epsilon)=(0,2|a_n|)$, which means $|f(x)|< 2|a_n|x^n$.

Comment: I'm not that experienced with limits, but I'm not sure how it rigorously follows that if the limit is $a_n$, that there exists a large enough $x_0$. Can you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: @Ayy_Lmao I added some details, does that help?